# Evans Chapter 4 Problem 16, initial value problem to Schrödinger equation, convergence

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Problem 16** states to discuss the sense in which $u(\cdot,t) \rightarrow g $ as $t\rightarrow 0^+$ defined by $$ u(x,t) =  \frac{1}{(4\pi i t)^{n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\frac{i |x-y|^2}{4t}}g(y)dy \ \ \ (x\in \mathbb{R}^n, \ t >0) $$
using some Lemma.
Schrödinger equation given by:
$$
\begin{cases}
iu_{t} + \Delta u = 0 & \quad \text{in } \  \mathbb{R}^{n} \times (0, \infty), \label{schrgl}\\
u = g & \quad \text{on  } \  \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \{t = 0\}.
\end{cases}
$$

I have tried to show the pointwise convergence $u(\cdot,t) \rightarrow g$ for $t \rightarrow 0$, given $g$ is smooth, compactly supported and am almost there, but a factor of $(-1)^n$ is bothering me.

There is a lemma from the book L.Evans PDE page 221.

Lemma: Let $a \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then
$$
\frac{1}{(4 t i \pi)^{n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\frac{i}{4t} |y|^2} a(y) dy = a(0)+ O(t)  \quad \quad \text{ for } t \rightarrow 0.
$$

If $g \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then the shifted $y \mapsto g(x-y)=:a(y)$ is also in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It holds $a(0) = g(x)$ and $a(x-y)=g(y)$.
It makes sense to make the substitution $z=x-y$ in the integral of the lemma so that it is equal to $u(x,t)$, but the Jacobian determinant of this transformation is $(-1)^n$.

Overall, I have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
u(x,t) &= \frac{1}{(4 t i \pi)^{n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\frac{i}{4t} |x-y|^2} g(y) dy\\ 
&= \frac{1}{(4 t i \pi)^{n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\frac{i}{4t} |x-y|^2} a(x-y) dy\\ 
&= \frac{(-1)^n}{(4 t i \pi)^{n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\frac{i}{4t} |y|^2} a(y) dy \\
&= (-1)^na(0)+O(t)\\
&= (-1)^ng(x)+O(t)
\end{aligned}
$$
which does not necessarily provide the pointwise convergence for odd $n$.
Where is my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: Change of variables formula has an absolute value on the determinant!

Comment: @peek-a-boo rookie mistake, thank you :)